# Displaying .PNG file folders generated from MBUtil in HTML Doc

Tags: leaflet, html

I recently followed this tutorial http://blog.davidelner.com/create-map-with-tilemill-and-leaflet/ that illustrated how to generate PNG tiles from Mbtile data sources. I was successful in creating the PNG tile folder dictionary on my local machine with the MBUtil utility. I wanted to know how would I serve the tiles in my .HTML document for offline use. This is what I currently have in my script but have been unsuccesful in displaying the tiles.

```
  var newLayer = L.tileLayer('file:///C:/Users/067626/Documents/GitHub/mbutil/libya/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 8 });
  map.addLayer(newLayer);
```

Comment: Why not use [Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles)?

Comment: IvanSanchez I get an "Error 500 Something went wrong on our end." When I attempt to open the link.

Comment: @ElDuderino [temporary server incident](https://twitter.com/gitlabstatus/status/865113186130948097) at GitLab. Works fine now.